Detect (and replace) math symbols in a string
TL;DR; How can I detect the presence of math symbols in a string?
I collect a lot of text data from others, through sources like google forms or directly in spreadsheets. Often the individuals doing the data entry copy text from somewhere else, say a webpage or PDF and along with the text comes math symbols.
Example string where  $\pi$ is copied as a symbol. "and π-d orbital"
R reads this in perfectly fine, and in markdown code it will even print/display it perfectly fine in an HTML format (see example). However, I need to render this text content to PDF.
Which of course Latex does not like and throws the following error
! LaTeX Error: Unicode character μ (U+03BC)
               not set up for use with LaTeX.

I would like to write some gsub/str_detect type code to find any special characters so I can replace them with their proper latex symbol: $\pi$.
I tried the following code to detect non-letter characters, but that didn't work (returned a FALSE, meaning it didn't detect the symbols).
stringr::str_detect("and π-d orbital", "[a-zA-Z]", negate = TRUE)

Suggestions? Is there a LaTeX solution?

Setting negate = TRUE is basically saying, "does this string not include any characters in "[a-zA-Z]"?". This is a different question from what you want, which is "does this string include any characters that aren’t in "[a-zA-Z]" ?". To ask that question, use ^ inside []. Note you’ll also want to include whitespace, "-", and any other "acceptable" characters.
stringr::str_detect("and π-d orbital", "[^\\s\\-a-zA-Z]")
# TRUE


This is lacking due to the notion of punctuations not being math symbols yet it will show as true

That’s why I note that OP will need to add any other characters they consider acceptable, such as punctuation.

Why? a math symbol is generally greek letters. That will be way closer. eg gsub("\\P{Greek}", "", "and π-d orbital", perl = TRUE) should delete everything that is non greek

That’s a good approach, and I wasn’t aware you could specifically identify Greek characters that way so thanks for teaching me. Why don’t you post that as an answer?

Well still does not meet the question requirements. I can only translate to $p$ and not $\pi$ which is not a solution

@Onyambu --- ooooo... this. This may be a different solution/work around  If i can negate that sentence to turn all greek to missing.
And YES I didn't realize you could search for greek!

Webscrape a greek to LaTeX dictionary, e.g. that of the Unofficial LaTeX2e reference manual.
> library(rvest)
> l <- 'https://latexref.xyz/Greek-letters.html'
> s <- html_table(read_html(l))[[1]][1:2] |> sapply(strsplit, ', ') |> 
+   apply(1, data.frame) |> Reduce(f=rbind)
> x <- "and π-d orbital"
> stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed(x, s$Symbol, s$Command, vectorize_all=FALSE)
[1] "and \\pi-d orbital"

If it's not just greek, you can include different ones. You may have to remove a backslash, depending on your circumstances.

Negating @Onyambu's solution allowed me to "delete" the greek letters - which gives me a good alternative solution that I can implement. I don't need to find/replace the greek if I can show the original submitter where their errors are (make them fix it!)
I'm going to mark this as answered but thank you also @zephryl for teaching me how to negate regex - which eventually got me to the same place.

you could use a dictionary with all the greek letters and their names to replace accordingly
